# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'beta' when trying to add model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My overall goal has been to save and load model data. I have been trying to do this in the policy.py file in the policy.py github file: https://github.com/pat-coady/trpo. However, this file uses model subclassing which has given me endless problems I can't figure out.

So I am trying to update the code to use a functional model instead, because I know this can save and load model data in the h5 file quite easily. However, I'm running into this error:

'''

```
current_dir=/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybullet_envs/bullet
Value Params -- h1: 50, h2: 15, h3: 5, lr: 0.00258
2020-06-05 17:38:00.976594: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/home/ryan/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
2020-06-05 17:38:00.976625: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-06-05 17:38:00.976646: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (ryan-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-06-05 17:38:00.976855: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-05 17:38:00.999796: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 1999965000 Hz
2020-06-05 17:38:01.000160: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x56688e0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-05 17:38:01.000178: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Ant->8,CartPole->1, or Humanoid-17
Policy Params -- h1: 50, h2: 44, h3: 40, lr: 0.000136, logvar_speed: 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 373, in <module>
    main(**vars(args))
  File "train.py", line 331, in main
    policy.update(observes, actions, advantages, logger)  # update policy
  File "/home/ryan/trpo_fractal6NN/trpo/policy.py", line 58, in update
    K.set_value(self.model.beta, self.beta)
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'beta'
```

'''

So for whatever reason, when I try to add the weight named 'beta (line 152),' it doesn't seem to register. Here is the code that I've currently been running on the policy.py file in https://github.com/ryanmaxwell96/trpo_fractal6NN/blob/master/policy.py.

How can I fix this issue or how can I save and load model values with model sublcassing?

Thanks

Comment: Should the line 152 be `self.model.beta = self.model.add_weight('beta', initializer='zeros', trainable=False)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what else it would be, but that is how it was in pat-coady's code

Comment: Oh and I should add that it seems to have correct syntax with subclassed model. But as I said, I can't save and load training data, or use tensorboard to create a architectural graph with model subclassing which is why I've been trying to convert it to either a functional model or sequential model